# nginx split_clients configuration does not split traffic to multiple upstreams

Tags: nginx

I want to test split traffic with nginx to 2 hosts (run as docker containers).

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
upstream exercim {
    server host.docker.internal:8081;
}

upstream nutshell {
    server host.docker.internal:8082;
}

split_clients "${remote_addr}" $backend {
    50% exercim;
    *   nutshell;
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location /exercim/ {
        proxy_pass  http://$backend;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

$remote_addr contains an IP address.

Still the traffic is not split. Always th upstream exercim is used. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: How are you testing it? How many remote addresses are you using?

Comment: I'm testing with one client, making subsequent calls. I expected, that every other call should go to the second upstream (in average :D)

Comment: That's not what [split clients](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html) is trying to achieve. If you had 100 clients, you would expect half of them to go to each upstream. But each individual client would always use the **same** upstream, selected based on the hash of their IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)'s answer solved the problem for me.